# Android application port of PHP/mySQL website - should i be using WebViews?

Tags: android, android-webview, leaflet

I am in the process of learning how to make an android application for my website.

I have learnt how to make menus, navigation and the like. I was just curious as to the best way to execute what I am trying to develop.

So.. my website shows establishments within a given distance of an inputted postcode on a map using the leaflet javascript mapping framework.

Essentially, I want the same functionality on my app, except using the users GPS location.

From my very basic knowledge/research, Google Maps integrates directly with the android SDK. I do not however want to use Google Maps because of its usage restrictions etc.

Am I correct to think that to use leaflet within my app, the only way is to use a WebView? If not, what are the alternatives, and which is best?

Further to the above, on the web version of the site you can then click on an establishment and it will take you to a page of details/reviews.

I am aware that there is a way, but would it be more logical to again simply use a webview to load an app-specific, simplified version of my website?

Other smaller things that could add to the functionality of the app - if i wanted to allow users to update their profiles etc. Again this could be done with a webview, but it could also be done with a form, and a link on the action menu..

Essentially my question is, given the web version is developed in PHP, mySQL, and javascript.. what is the best way to port it to a simple android app?

Many Thanks

Comment: webview type of apps are poor implementations of what a full app can do. It's possible? yes. Other people do? absolutely. The final result will be a good app (in terms of usability, speed, smoothness, features)? I doubt. But that's only my two cents. ps.: what do you mean by: google maps usage restrictions?

Comment: Google Maps has restrictions which my service will most likely go over... WHat about as to whether it is possible to use leaflet without webviews..?

Comment: leaflet is a javascript library. So the quick answer is 'no, Android is developed in Java'. But the data for the leaflet is backed by the cloudmade maps that does have a native Android library http://code.google.com/p/android-cloudmade-api/ . But I'll insist in asking you on what limitations are you referring to on the Google Maps SDK, because I developed several Android projects with Gmaps and I can't think of anything you can't do with it.

Comment: I'm also interested in the limitations you mentioned.

Comment: I think it was 25,000 requests a day, and you cannot save any of their data. These limitations make it worthless to my project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to do part of the functionality in Android and reuse php modules of your webpage over http connections.

It's possible that you can develop leaflet functionality with any Android library or app like Google Places (Maps).